# Interrupt priority

Tags: drivers

I am new to using Ubuntu (Linux) in an embedded system. I am trying to find a way to change the interrupt priority. I tried rtirq script, but nothing is changed.

Can anyone advise me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using 20.04. LTS